# How to open a file larger than 20 MB in Intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

If I try to open a text file larger than 20MB, I get the message: File `<path>` is too large (21.97MB). Where could I relax this restriction?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found by inspecting intellij source code:
you have to edit the property `idea.max.intellisense.filesize` in `idea.properties` located in `idea_home/bin`.

The maximum file size to load `= max(20MB, <value of idea.max.intellisense.filesize>)`